# LogStash - Failed to instantiate type net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender

Tags: spring-boot, logstash, logback, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I am working on Springboot Microservcies & for monitoring Im using ELK Stack. I am using docker containers for running ELK as per this [guide](https://piotrminkowski.wordpress.com/2017/04/05/part-2-creating-microservices-monitoring-with-spring-cloud-sleuth-elk-and-zipkin/).

ELK is up and running, I am starting my Logstash by,

```
docker run -d -it --name logstash -p 5000:5000 logstash -e 
'input { tcp { port => 5000 codec => "json" } } 
output { elasticsearch { hosts => ["192.168.99.100"] index => "micro-%{serviceName}"} }'
```

My Pom details,

[image]

logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread, %X{X-B3-TraceId:-},%X{X-B3-SpanId:-}] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STASH"
        class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
        <destination>192.168.99.100:5000</destination>

        <encoder
            class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
            <providers>
                <mdc /> <!-- MDC variables on the Thread will be written as JSON fields -->
                <context /> <!--Outputs entries from logback's context -->
                <version /> <!-- Logstash json format version, the @version field in the output -->
                <logLevel />
                <loggerName />

                <pattern>
                    <pattern>
                        {
                        "serviceName": "customer-service"
                        }
                    </pattern>
                </pattern>

                <threadName />
                <message />

                <logstashMarkers />
                <arguments />

                <stackTrace />
            </providers>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="STASH" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

When I run my main class, I get an Logstash Error,

```
14:33:22,066 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
14:33:22,067 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
14:33:22,067 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [xyzxyz/logback.xml]
14:33:22,251 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
14:33:22,254 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
14:33:22,281 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
14:33:22,297 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
14:33:22,450 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender]
14:33:22,452 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Could not create an Appender of type [net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender]. ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender
    at ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassNameAndParameter(OptionHelper.java:69)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassName(OptionHelper.java:45)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassName(OptionHelper.java:34)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction.begin(AppenderAction.java:52)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callBeginAction(Interpreter.java:269)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.startElement(Interpreter.java:145)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.startElement(Interpreter.java:128)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:50)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:165)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:152)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:110)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:53)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:75)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:150)
    at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:84)
    at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
    at  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
    at  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
    at  at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685)
    at  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:191)
    at  at pl.piomin.microservices.customer.Application.main(Application.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender
    at  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassNameAndParameter(OptionHelper.java:56)
    at  ... 24 common frames omitted
14:33:22,452 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@11:67 - ActionException in Action for tag [appender] ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ActionException: ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender
    at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ActionException: ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction.begin(AppenderAction.java:76)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callBeginAction(Interpreter.java:269)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.startElement(Interpreter.java:145)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.startElement(Interpreter.java:128)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:50)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:165)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:152)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:110)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:53)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:75)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:150)
    at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:84)
    at  at org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.<clinit>(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)
    at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:357)
    at  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:155)
    at  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
    at  at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:685)
    at  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:191)
    at  at pl.piomin.microservices.customer.Application.main(Application.java:14)
Caused by: ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassNameAndParameter(OptionHelper.java:69)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassName(OptionHelper.java:45)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassName(OptionHelper.java:34)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction.begin(AppenderAction.java:52)
    at  ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender
    at  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at  at ch.qos.logback.core.util.OptionHelper.instantiateByClassNameAndParameter(OptionHelper.java:56)
    at  ... 24 common frames omitted
14:33:22,453 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
14:33:22,453 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
14:33:22,456 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Could not find an appender named [STASH]. Did you define it below instead of above in the configuration file?
14:33:22,456 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - See http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#appender_order for more details.
14:33:22,456 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
14:33:22,458 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@2096442d - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

14:33:24.286 [main, ,] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Could not create an Appender of type [net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender]. ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@11:67 - ActionException in Action for tag [appender] ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ActionException: ch.qos.logback.core.util.DynamicClassLoadingException: Failed to instantiate type net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Could not find an appender named [STASH]. Did you define it below instead of above in the configuration file?
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - See http://logback.qos.ch/codes.html#appender_order for more details.
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:151)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.reinitialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:195)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithConventions(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:106)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:277)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:255)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:224)
    at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.java:200)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:121)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:330)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:140)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:84)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:1)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:166)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:138)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:121)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:330)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
    at pl.piomin.microservices.customer.Application.main(Application.java:14)
14:33:24.295 [main, ,] INFO  o.s.b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener - Application failed to start with classpath: [xyzxyz/,
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!! Should I be using any different version Logstash dependencies?

Answer (score 21):

It Seems you haven't added dependencies properly. Try to add

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
                <version>4.9</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.3</version>
            </dependency>
```

and run mvn clean compile install.
It should work properly.

Comment: adding logstash-logback-encoder also fixes `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder` thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes it is an **issue with ID**E. If you copied your project from other machine, in Intellij Idea try to

```
File -> Invalidate Caches & Restart -> Maven -> Reload All Maven Projects.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with `logstash-logback-encoder` version `6.6`

Making sure that all following dependencies are resolved and connected to the project - resolved the issue:

```xml
 <properties>
        <logback.version>1.2.4</logback.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
                <version>${logback.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <version>${logback.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
                <version>${logback.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

refer to official readme otherwise)
https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder